# Helm under MicroK8S giving: "Error: could not find a ready tiller pod"

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, helm

I need learn about Kubernetes, Helm, conjure-up and also need install Eclipe-Che, and to it I did:
On a fresh install of [Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server X64] running as virtual machine inside **vmware workstation** Im installing MicroK8S and Helm.

Its on a **fresh Ubuntu install** and the **0nly** script block im pasting on terminal is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
microk8s.kubectl version
alias kubectl='microk8s.kubectl'
alias docker='microk8s.docker'
kubectl describe nodes | egrep 'Name:|Roles:|Taints:'
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
kubectl get nodes
sudo snap install helm --classic
kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule \
            --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
            --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account=tiller
helm version
helm ls
kubectl get po -n kube-system
```

The script block above with each output on terminal is:

```
myUser@myServer:~$ sudo snap install microk8s --classic
microk8s v1.13.4 from Canonical✓ installed
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10

myUser@myServer:~$ microk8s.kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info { 
    Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.4", 
    GitCommit:"c27b913frrr1a6c480c287433a087698aa92f0b1", 
    GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-28T13:37:52Z", 
    GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
    The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8080 was 
      refused - did you specify the right host or port?

myUser@myServer:~$ alias kubectl='microk8s.kubectl'

myUser@myServer:~$ alias docker='microk8s.docker'

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl describe nodes | egrep 'Name:|Roles:|Taints:'
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8080 was 
     refused - did you specify the right host or port?

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl taint nodes --all \
         node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8080 was 
     refused - did you specify the right host or port?

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8080 was 
        refused - did you specify the right host or port?

myUser@myServer:~$ sudo snap install helm --classic
helm 2.13.0 from Snapcrafters installed

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl create serviceaccount tiller \
              --namespace kube-system
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "kube-system" not found

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding \
             tiller-cluster-rule \
             --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
             --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller-cluster-rule created

myUser@myServer:~$ helm init --service-account=tiller
Creating /home/myUser/.helm 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/repository 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/repository/cache 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/repository/local 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/plugins 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/starters 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/cache/archive 
Creating /home/myUser/.helm/repository/repositories.yaml 
Adding stable repo with URL: 
   https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com 
Adding local repo with URL: http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts 
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/myUser/.helm.
Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been 
        installed into your Kubernetes Cluster.
Please note: by default, Tiller is deployed with an 
        insecure 'allow unauthenticated users' policy.
To prevent this, run `helm init` with 
        the --tiller-tls-verify flag.
For more information on 
   securing your installation see: 
   https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#securing-your-helm-installation
Happy Helming!

myUser@myServer:~$ helm version
Client: &version.Version { 
   SemVer:"v2.13.0",
   GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", 
   GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller

myUser@myServer:~$ helm ls
Error: could not find tiller

myUser@myServer:~$ kubectl get po -n kube-system 
No resources found.
```

As you can see its also refusung connection on 127.0.0.1:8080 too and with the help of @aurelius I improved script above but as you can see its yet giving the same error:

> Error: could not find a ready tiller pod

And I did the [**fix** described in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49764370) as you can see above.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2295) opened on Github pointing to **fix** above and closing as solved but it doesn't solve the problem.

There is one telling the problem is with snap version of LXD that dont integrate with conjure-up, he tell to install LXD from apt packages and his full explanation is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/959771.
I will try it to see if it works too and come back here.

Comment: is the tiller pod there? is it working? if not - why is it not working?

Comment: @4c74356b41 'helm init' is supposed to create the tile, all above was done on a fresh install.

Comment: i know, i'm asking did it create it? is it working? whats the error?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Calling 'helm init' create entries, no error message and 'Happy Helming' message at end

Comment: @4c74356b41 'kubectl describe po' returns nothing

Comment: by the way, im doing it all inside a Vmware virtual machine

Comment: kubectl get po -n kube-system after that kubectl describe po tillerpodname -n kube-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All was need is:

```
helm repo update
```

The full set of commands here :

```
# Ensure there disk space to install all
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
sudo snap remove lxc
sudo snap remove lxd
sudo apt-get remove --purge lxc 
sudo apt-get remove --purge lxd 
sudo apt-get autoremove
# can throw error, ensure each purgue/uninstall above
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install tmux lxc lxd zfsutils-linux 
df -h => 84% Free, 32G
{ SNAPSHOT - beforeLxdInit }
lxd init
    ipv6:none
ifconfig | grep flags
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.ens33.disable_ipv6=1  
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1  
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lxcbr0.disable_ipv6=1  
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lxdbr0.disable_ipv6=1  
time sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
{ SNAPSHOT - beforeConjureUp }
conjure-up => CHOICE = { microk8s }
alias kubectl='microk8s.kubectl'
#------------------------------------
# not necessary enable all but its a test
microk8s.enable storage
microk8s.enable registry    
microk8s.enable dns dashboard ingress istio metrics-server prometheus fluentd jaeger
#------------------------------------
time sudo snap install helm --classic
helm init
kubectl create serviceaccount --namespace kube-system tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
kubectl patch deploy --namespace kube-system tiller-deploy -p '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"serviceAccount":"tiller"}}}}'
helm search
# Before update the repo it throw an error:
helm version
    Error: could not find a ready tiller pod 
# Then update the repo:
helm repo update
# After update the repo it was OK:
helm version
    Client: &version.Version { 
            SemVer:"v2.13.0", 
            GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6",
            GitTreeState:"clean"
        }
    Server: &version.Version { 
            SemVer:"v2.13.0", 
            GitCommit:"79d07943b03aea2b76c12644b4b54733bc5958d6", 
            GitTreeState:"clean" 
        }
#------------------------------------
helm install stable/mysql
df -h | grep sda {
    Filesystem:/dev/sda2,
    Size:40G,  
    Used:12G,  
    Avail:26G, 
    Use%:31% 
    Mounted-on:/
    }
{ SNAPSHOT - afterFixErrorBeforeEclipseChe }
#------------------------------------
========================================================================================================================
# Looks like it added a messy OverlayFS
df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           393M  2.5M  390M   1% /run
    /dev/sda2        40G   12G   26G  31% /
    tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    /dev/loop0       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
    tmpfs           393M     0  393M   0% /run/user/1000
    tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /var/lib/lxd/shmounts
    tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /var/lib/lxd/devlxd
    /dev/loop1      110M  110M     0 100% /snap/conjure-up/1045
    /dev/loop2      205M  205M     0 100% /snap/microk8s/492
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M  4.7M   60M   8% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
    shm              64M  4.7M   60M   8% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes$
    overlay          40G   12G   26G  31% /var/snap/microk8s/common/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/k8s.$
========================================================================================================================

kubectl run eclipseche --image=eclipse/che-server:nightly
    deployment.apps/eclipseche2 created
    ------------------------------------
    # Cant found a way to follow the advise below, cant find the equivalent syntax
    kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 
    is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. 
    Use 
    kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 
    or 
    kubectl create instead

kubectl get pods
    NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    brown-hyena-mysql-75f584d69d-rbfv4        1/1     Running   0          72m
    default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-z7jb4     1/1     Running   0          91m
    eclipseche-589954dc99-d4bxm               1/1     Running   0          6m13s
    nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-p88nm   1/1     Running   0          91m

kubectl get svc
    NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
    brown-hyena-mysql      ClusterIP   10.152.184.38   <none>        3306/TCP   74m
    default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.152.184.99   <none>        80/TCP     93m
    kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.152.184.1    <none>        443/TCP    99m

microk8s.kubectl describe pod eclipseche-589954dc99-d4bxm | grep "IP:"
    IP:  10.1.1.54

sudo apt-get install net-tools nmap

nmap 10.1.1.54 | grep open
    8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
$ microk8s.enable helm

$ microk8s.helm init --override spec.selector.matchLabels.'name'='tiller',spec.selector.matchLabels.'app'='helm' --output yaml | sed 's@apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1@apiVersion: apps/v1@' | microk8s.kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 0):

Error happens because you do not have service account for Tiller. You can achieve that by running:

`kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system`

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule \
 --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
 --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller`

`helm init --service-account=tiller`

You can find more information about Tiller [here](https://helm.sh/docs/install/#installing-tiller).

Comment: Thanks for the help but even after your fix the problem remains the same, I updated the question with your fix and added a block that im pasting on terminal, as you can realize im realy new to kubernetes and still learning the basics .